# Copy files if attributes match

Tags: xml, batch-file

please bear with me since I'am new to batch.

I'am trying to copy files from one location to another only if two attributes are matching.

I tried around and modify but didn't succeed with:

```
set dSource=\\server5\Datapool
set dTarget=C:\Users\folder1
set fType=*.xml
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:<>" %%a, in ('findstr "Name=\"Marc\"" *.xml|findstr "testcar=\"BENZ231\"" *.xml') do (
    copy /V "%%a" "%dTarget%\" 2>nul
)
```

So my goal is to copy XML files only if Marc+BENZ231 match.

XML files do look like this:

```
<testInfo testDuration="57" holidayCount="0" completedtask="12" Name="Marc" testVersion="13" testcar="BENZ231" 
 <result testStepName="locating" sequenceNrResult="1" testStepResult="OK">
 etc.
 </testInfo>
</testresult>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-----------------test.bat--------------
@echo off&pushd \\server5\Datapool
for /f %%a in ('dir /b ^| find ".xml"') do for /f %%A in ('type %%a ^| find /I "Marc" ^| find /I "BENZ231"') do copy %%a C:\Users\folder1
-----------------test.bat--------------
```

Got it now. This one just worked fine for me!

Comment: will give you false positives: "Marcus", "Marco Polo", "Camarco", "Benz2315", ...

Answer (score 0):

`findstr string1 string2` searches for `string1` OR `string2`. You need AND. If both strings are on the same line, it's easy; just find the second string in the result of finding the first string:

```
findstr "Name=\"Marc\"" test.xml|findstr "testcar=\"BENZ231\""
```

(note: you have to escape every literally `"`)

To properly process it in a `for`, you have to escape some special characters (`|` here):

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:<>" %%a, in ('findstr findstr "Name=\"Marc\"" test.xml^|findstr "testcar=\"BENZ231\""') do (
```

Attention: `copy %%a ...' is not a good idea. You need the file name here. Put another`for`around to process each file individually (and you don't need tokens here; just set`delims`to "none"`"delims="`):

```
for %%f in (*.xml) do (
  for /F "delims=" %%a, in ('findstr "Name=\"Marc\"" "%%f"^|findstr "testcar=\"BENZ231\""') do (
    copy /V "%%f" "%dTarget%\" 2>nul
  )
)
```

If the strings are (might be) on different lines, you have to use a different approach (parsing the file twice; `&&` works as "if the first string is found then"):

```
findstr "Name=\"Marc\"" test.xml >nul && findstr "testcar=\"BENZ231\"" test.xml
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response and information ! I'll update it in my orignal post.Further I do also have to modify my copy but I don't know how. And yes, both strings are on the same line.