# Extracting Files with newest date

Tags: batch-file

I'am trying to extract specified XML Data from one folder to another.

The problem is I only need the newest ones. The current date should determine the newest XML files. For example today: 04/20/2017

My scirpt as follows:

```
-----------------test.bat--------------
@echo off&pushd \\server5\Datapool
for /f %%a in ('dir /b ^| find ".xml"') do for /f %%A in ('type %%a ^| find /I "Marc" ^| find /I "BENZ231"') do copy %%a C:\Users\folder1
-----------------test.bat--------------
```

So my goal is to extract the newest XML files into another folder only if "Marc" + "BENZ231" match.

btw: both strings "marc" and "benz231"are on the same line.

Comment: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with XML, and I've removed the tag. Just because you're trying to move files with an XML extension, it does not make the question about XML. Please don't tag spam; use **only** the tags that are actually relevant to your post. You can determine if they are by reading the tag description before using it. Tags have meaning and relevance here, which is why each one has a description regarding what it's about and for what it should be used. Thanks.

Comment: I will take this into account. Thanks

Comment: Please don't post [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43493012/2152082). Use `xcopy` instead of `copy` - it has a function to copy only files newer than a given date. Also the `/m` parameter could be of interest. See `xcopy /?` for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
rem -----------------test.bat--------------
@echo off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "file=" 
set "srcFolder=\\server5\Datapool"
set "dstFolder=C:\Users\folder1"

rem language independent time
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set "Tm=%%a"
set "today=%Tm:~0,4%%Tm:~4,2%%Tm:~6,2%"

pushd "%srcFolder%"
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b /o:d *.xml`) do (
  set "fileTime=%%~ta"
  rem set "fileTime_spanish=!fileTime:~6,4!!fileTime:~3,2!!fileTime:~0,2!"
  set "fileTime_english=!fileTime:~6,4!!fileTime:~0,2!!fileTime:~3,2!"
  if "!fileTime_english!" equ "%today%" (
    findstr /irc:"marc.*BENZ231" /c:"BENZ231.*marc" %%a && copy "%%a" "%dstFolder%"
  )
)
popd
EndLocal
exit/B
rem -----------------test.bat--------------
```

Note the `/o:d` switch of the `dir` command that list files sorting by date (newest last). Changed the `for` loop to set the `file` variable to all files matching the `dir` wildcard, and the strings passed to `findstr`. As `dir` has listed files sorted by date, the `file` variable will contain the newest file according both conditions.

**EDITED 25/04/2017**

Note now the use of `delayed expansion` as `filetime_xxx` is updated inside a block (anything within parens), and delayed variable expansion is now made enclosing variable name in `!`.

You may need to adjust `filetime_xxx` to fit whatever date sort order your system may use.

This is not the best approach, but is a starting point.

Comment: To also support possible file names with spaces you'd need to add `delims=` or `tokens=*` to the for options and double quote `"%file%"`

Comment: @LotPings you're right! I wasn't in front of my computer. post edited.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply and sorry for my late response. It works for me halfway but only copies one single file into it. It should copy all new ones for Marc + Benz231. Am i doing sth. wrong? edit: I propably didn't explain myself the right way. I want to copy all files from todays date if attributes mentioned above match. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: This really helped me! Thank you so much for your effort ! Appreciate it ! :)